# What is this HTML construct called and how do I target it with CSS? i.e., <span data-v-4fbf27d8="">

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I simply don't know what this HTML construct with a `data-v-4fbf27d8` is called. It's not a `class` or a `ID`.

What is `data-v-4fbf27d8=""` called?

```
<h2 class="rebrand" data-v-4fbf27d8="">
<span data-v-4fbf27d8="">Text</span>
</h2>
```

How do I target that span div with a `display:none`? With a wildcard? Must I use jQuery?

Comment: It's called [Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: One never HAS to use jquery! See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes for info on how to use data attributes, including in CSS selectors.